# storing & moving historical data

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have this macro that is supposed to cut a table, and paste said table one column to the right each time it's ran. Once I finish this I intend to have it copy the first column of that table, and paste it as value so that the data itself stays, and not the formulas. The end goal is for it to move across excel kind of like a train, where it stores old data, but at the same time is processes new data with the function.

I'm having an issue with the first cut/paste section though, I am getting "Range of object method failed" each time it reaches the paste section. Any help is appreciated.

[image: example of the table (each of those cells is a formula that calls data)]

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Worksheet")
todminone = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Today", ws.Range("A1:XFD1"), 0)
ws.Range(Cells(1, todminone - 1), Cells(42, 16384)).Cut 
ws.Range(Cells(1, todminone)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

Comment: Every call to Cells/Range should have a qualifying worksheet reference, so (eg) `ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, todminone - 1), ws.Cells(42, 16384)).Cut`

Comment: `ws.Range(Cells(1, todminone)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas` can just be `ws.Cells(1, todminone).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas`

Comment: Hey @TimWilliams I didn't know it needed to be specific each time that's my bad. I made those changes, now I'm just getting "PasteSpecial method of Range Class failed". Normally I find doing something like this simple when it's vertical, but I've never done it horizontally with column index #'s.

Comment: For pasteSpecial I think you need to use Copy not Cut?

Comment: I'm super late on this, but the method that worked for me was offset. Ty!